# Why is my AppData folder not indexed by Telescope and how can I fix it simply?

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt, plugin-telescope

I could not find help with Google nor ChatGPT. Maybe there's something wrong with my telescope config?

Comment: I suspect that AppData is rather large and Telescope needs time to index it. Since it is asynchronous you could have the wrong impression that it is not doing. Do you have the same behavior for a small AppData subfolder?

Comment: It seems to work fine on my machine running the command: `:Telescope find_files`.

Comment: How can I test for a small AppData subfolder without moving it outside of AppData? I did wait quite a while, like 20s.

Comment: Do you have the problem when the current working directory is e.g.: `~\AppData\Local\nvim`?

Comment: Ah yes it works. Maybe Telescope only indexes the files below the current location?

Comment: That is my conviction (the current working directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telescope is indexing the files under the current working directory. To make sure `:Telescope find_files` shows you the file of `~\AppData` you have first to change the working directory:

```
:cd ~\AppData
```